# I have ran my program but nothing shows up cant find the issue with the program

Tags: python

im trying to do a case study of a guessing game but its not working

fixing indent 
putting breezypythongui.py into the same folder but still nothing showing up

```
import random
from breezypythongui import EasyFrame

class GuessingGame(EasyFrame):
    """playing a guessing game with a user."""

    def __init__(self):
        """setting up the window,widgets and data."""
        EasyFrame.__init__(self, title = "Guessing Game")
        # Initialize the instance variables for the data
        self.myNumber = random.randint(1,100)
        self.count = 0
        # Create and add widgets to the window
        greeting = "Guess a number between 1 and 100."
        self.hintLabel = self.addLabel(text = greeting,
                                       row = 0, column = 0,
                                       sticky = "NSEW",
                                       columnspan = 2)
        self.addLabel(text = "Your guess", row = 1, column = 0)
        self.guessField = self.addIntegerField(0, row = 1, column = 1)
        # Buttons have no command attributes yet
        self.nextButton = self.addButton(text = "Next",row = 2,
                                         column = 0,
                                         command = self.next)
        self.newButton = self.addButton(text = "New game",
                                        row = 2,column = 1,
                                        command = self.reset)


    def nextGuess(self):
        """Processes the user's next guess."""
        self.count += 1
        guess = self.guessField.getNumber()
        if guess == self.myNumber:
            self.hintLabel["text"] = "You've guessed it in " + \
                                     str(self.count) + " attempts!"
            self.nextButton["state"] = "disabled"
        elif guess < self.myNumber:
            self.hintLabel["text"] = "Sorry, too small!"
        else:
            self.hintLabel["text"] = "Sorry, too large!"

    def newGame(self):
        """Resets the data and GUI to their original states."""
        self.myNumber = random.randint(1, 100)
        self.count = 0
        greeting = ("Guess a number between 1 and 100.")
        self.hintLabel["text"] = greeting
        self.guessField.setNumber(0)
        self.nextButton["state"] = "normal"

def main():
    """Instantiate and pop up the window."""
    GuessingGame().mainloop()
    if __name__=="__main__":
        main()
```

i expect the program to tell me if im close to the right number or two low

Comment: use button `{}` to correctly format code.

Comment: I don't know `EasyFrame` but shouldn't be some `show()`, `pack()`, `display()`, etc like in other GUIs ?

Comment: if it is code from your file then remove indention in `if __name__=="__main__":`

Answer (score 0):

I can't run it but I see wrong indention in `if __name__=="__main__":`. Remove indention.

```
def main():
    """Instantiate and pop up the window."""
    GuessingGame().mainloop()

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: i fixed the indention but now its show 'GuessingGame' object has no attribute 'next'

Comment: so old problem is resolved and you have new problem - you should create new question on new page. And you will have place to put full Traceback.

Comment: you assign function to button `command = self.next` but you don't have this function in class (`def next(self):`) - so what do you expecte? BTW: you will have the same problem with `command = self.reset`